# Merge intervals with upper bound for time

Tags: algorithm, intervals

The regular [merge interval question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660111/algorithm-for-merging-overlapping-intervals) is well known - and has an O(nLogn) solution. However, I was recently asked a follow up question - What if we had an upper bound on the start and end time values? Could we improve our runtime? That is - assume the start/end time can have a maximum value of C.

Answer (score 2):

If it were possible to improve runtime when C was known, then you could search for C in O(n) and be faster even if you do not know C, right? I think if you have anoter costraint e.g., only whole numbers are possible as interval limits you could improve runtime.

Comment: Valid point. If the time intervals were whole numbers, were you thinking of a bucket sort approach?

Comment: Yes something like that. You could  memorize for each bucket how many start and endpoints it contains and then scan throug the buckets in order to get the final result. That would make it O(n + C)